# CSS Selector Within a Selector

Tags: css

Essentially what I am trying to do is have one element react as the hover state of a different element.

`.page-template-page-services-new .imgBlock:hover { .page-template-page-services-new .ButtonService {color: #6395ce; background-color: #fff; } }`

Not currently working - is this a thing? If not, how might I accomplish it. I know the selectors are correct, they work independently.

Comment: This needs additional elaboration.

Comment: I don't think you can have selector within selector in CSS

Comment: Will need to see the html to be able to give an answer

Comment: I don't think it's possible.. you should look for JavaScript event listener especially for the onHover event

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just append the inner selector to the outer one? Why do you need to nest them this way?

Comment: @BoltClock OP wants to style an element when another element *that is not its parent* is hovered (I think). Hence, JS must be used.

Comment: @Edmund Reed: Yeah, you're probably right.

Comment: You should add your HTML structure. otherwise we can only guess what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

What I *think* you are referring to is that you've seen something akin to

```
.selector-one{
  //style definitions
  .selector-two{
    //other style definitions
  }
}
```

This comes from pre-processors such as SCSS (Sass) or LESS, I'll assume you can do a quick google on those.

For the other part of your question, yes, you *can* style an element differently if it's parent container or even a sibling is hovered.

Example

```css
.container-hover:hover .red-on-hover{
 background-color:red;
}

.sibling-hover:hover + .sibling-hover{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-hover">
  <h3>Other Text</h3>
  <div class="red-on-hover">Background will turn red on hover</div>
</div>

<p class="sibling-hover"> When I am hovered, my sibling will be blue</p>
<p class="sibling-hover"> Blue? Blue</p>
```

For the sibling hover, please note that if you added more `.sibling-hover` elements that *all but the first one* would be able to turn blue if you hovered over it's immediately prior sibling.

Comment: don't forget about general sibling connector `~`

Comment: You are correct, but I'll be honest I've never had a case where I needed to use the `~` selector

Answer (score 0):

It can work if they have a parent child relationship.

```css
.page-template-page-services-new {
  background: #ccc;
}
.page-template-page-services-new .imgBlock:hover .ButtonService {
  color: #6395ce;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-template-page-services-new">
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="">
    <div class="ButtonService">
      <p>
        This is a test
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```